# jQuery ajax and load won't repeat in Chrome or IE8

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, servlets, loops, internet-explorer-8

I've found other threads discussing .load and .ajax with Chrome and IE, but none with my particular problem.

I'm using the following code to call in a response from a servlet.  The response should be 3 lines of text/html, but I can adjust to text/plain.

```
function checkProgress(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/myServlet",
        success: function(result) {
            $('#data').text(result);
            setTimeout(checkProgress, 2000);
        }

    });​
}
```

The idea here is to pull in the value ever 2 sec. and display in a div.

```
<div id="status" style="display:none;">                
            <h3>Status</h3>                
                <p id="data"></p>
            </div>
```

The problem that I am having is that this will only load 1 time in Chrome and IE8.  FF will repeat the load and I can see the value changing in browser.

Other issues I have seen talk about this not working at all in Chrome and IE8, but mine does work. It just will not repeat the load.

I have also tried this with .load because I want to maintain any html formatting and have encountered the same problem.  I'm willing to skip the formatting for now so I can get this to update.

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDITED**
Researching Chrome a little more, I've found that it stops the ajax script when I submit the form.  My page kicks off a rather lengthy servlet.  I'm using the Ajax call to return status updates from the servlet.  When I submit to start the servlet, the script that is running to report the status stops in Chrome. No errors. It just stops running.

This looks like a threading issue in Chrome.  Is there a better way of doing this?  Can I kick-off both the ajax and servlet at the same time with an onsubmit event?

Comment: I employed a combination of both the first 2 answers below and it is now working in IE8.  Chrome will still not repeat the update.  Could my interval be too short and firing some security flag in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE caches ajax requests. How about adding a random string along with the url to make it a new request every time ?

Set the cache property value to false. So jquery will add a unique timestamp to all requests so it wont be a cached response everytime.

```
function checkProgress(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/myServlet" ,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#data').text(result);
            setTimeout(checkProgress, 2000);
        }

    });​
}
```

Comment: Upon further testing, the cache was the problem in IE8.  Chrome is still holding out on me, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
setTimeout(checkProgress, 2000);
```

Change it to, you missed **()**:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    checkProgress();
}, 2000);
```